# How to schedule Oracle DBMS Jobs in a window

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dbms-scheduler

I want to create an Oracle DBMS Job that runs every week day (not on weekends) from 09:00 to 20:00 every 10 min. I wonder if I can do that in the `FREQ` parameter of the job definition or I have to create a `New Maintenance Window`.

It seems that with the solution proposed, the job runs at 9 and 20 only, and after first execution, when I run this query

```
select owner, job_name, next_run_date 
from dba_scheduler_jobs 
where JOB_NAME = 'GET_INVOICES_JOB';
```

I got `09/10/17 20:01:27,000000000 EUROPE/MADRID`

```
'freq=minutely; interval=10; byhour=9,20; byday=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI; exclude=Company_Holidays; bysetpos=-1'
```

Comment: What’s the frequency between 9:00 and 20:00?

Comment: I want the job execute every 10 minutes on the week days from 9:00 to 20:00...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this:

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
   job_name           =>  'jb_en_lopes',
   job_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action         =>  'pr_en_lopes',
   start_date         =>  '09-oct-2017 09:00:00 am',
   repeat_interval    =>  'freq=minutely; interval=10; byhour=9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20; byday=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI;',
   enabled            =>  true);
end;
```

When this scheduler in charge I get the results below :

```
select * 
  from dba_scheduler_job_log l
 where l.job_name = 'JB_EN_LOPES'
 order by l.log_date desc;

 LOG_ID LOG_DATE                            OPERATION   STATUS

1051594 10-OCT-17 09.59.01.197420 AM +03:00    RUN      SUCCEEDED  
1051592 10-OCT-17 09.58.02.229724 AM +03:00    RUN      SUCCEEDED  
1051590 10-OCT-17 09.57.03.177907 AM +03:00    RUN      SUCCEEDED  
1051588 10-OCT-17 09.56.01.197341 AM +03:00    RUN      SUCCEEDED
```

Where :

```
select owner, job_name, next_run_date                                  
  from dba_scheduler_jobs                                               
 where JOB_NAME = 'JB_EN_LOPES'; 

 OWNER    JOB_NAME       NEXT_RUN_DATE

 myschema JB_EN_LOPES   10-OCT-17 08.00.00.194958 PM +03:00
```

**Update :**

If you have no access to `dba_` views, then consider to replace those prefixes with `user_`, and remove `owner` column from the select list for the last query as

```
select job_name, next_run_date                                  
  from user_scheduler_jobs                                               
 where JOB_NAME = 'JB_EN_LOPES';
```

Comment: from 09:00 to 20:00 every 10 min, I forgot, sorry

Comment: @enLopes i've edited again by removing `bysetpos=-1` part(i've seen that is not suitable for minutely interval) and changed job_type to `STORED_PROCEDURE`

Comment: same result :-(

Comment: @enLopes i've added my results.

Comment: @enLopes and removed "exclude=Company_Holidays" part.

Comment: You should not use strings (i.e. `09-oct-2017 09:00:00 am`) for `TIMESTAMP` values. Use function `TO_TIMESTAMP` or `TIMESTAMP` literals. For such an interval you have to consider daylight saving times. If you don't provide a time zone at `start_date` then Oracle takes the current session time zone into account. This could be fine or not. If your `SESSIONTIMEZONE` is for example `+02:00` then the job execution might be shifted by one hour in winter season.See [Repeat Intervals and Daylight Savings](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN10020)

Answer (score -2):

I don't think this is possible:

Here are some repeat_interval examples that demonstrate the versatility and flexibility of the calendaring syntax:

Run at 10:00 pm daily from Monday to Friday:

```
FREQ=DAILY; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI; BYHOUR=22; BYMINUTE=0; BYSECOND=0;
```

Run every hour:

```
FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=1;
```

Run every 5 minutes:

```
FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=5;
```

Run every Friday at 9:00 am (All three examples are equivalent):

```
FREQ=DAILY; BYDAY=FRI; BYHOUR=9; BYMINUTE=0; BYSECOND=0;
FREQ=WEEKLY; BYDAY=FRI; BYHOUR=9; BYMINUTE=0; BYSECOND=0;
FREQ=YEARLY; BYDAY=FRI; BYHOUR=9; BYMINUTE=0; BYSECOND=0;
```

Run every other Friday:

```
FREQ=WEEKLY; INTERVAL=2; BYDAY=FRI;
```

Run on Monday of weeks 5, 10 and 15 every year:

```
FREQ=YEARLY; BYWEEKNO=5,10,15; BYDAY=MON
```

Run on the last day of every month.

```
FREQ=MONTHLY; BYMONTHDAY=-1;
```

Run on the next to last day of every month:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY; BYMONTHDAY=-2;
```

Run on March 10th (Both examples are equivalent):

```
FREQ=YEARLY; BYMONTH=MAR; BYMONTHDAY=10;
FREQ=YEARLY; BYDATE=0310;
```

Run every January 10, 11, 12, 13 and 14 (Both examples are equivalent):

```
FREQ=YEARLY; BYDATE=0110,0111,0112,0113,0114
FREQ=YEARLY; BYDATE=0110+SPAN:5D;
```

Run every 10 days:

```
FREQ=DAILY; INTERVAL=10;
```

Run daily at 4:15, 5:15, and 6:15PM:

```
FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=16,17,18; BYMINUTE=15; BYSECOND=0;
```

Run on the 15th day of every other month:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY; INTERVAL=2; BYMONTHDAY=15;
```

Run on the 29th day of every month:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY; BYMONTHDAY=29;
```

Run on the second Wednesday of each month:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY; BYDAY=2WED;
```

Run on the last Friday of the year:

```
FREQ=YEARLY; BYDAY=-1FRI;
```

Run every 50 hours:

```
FREQ=HOURLY; INTERVAL=50;
```

Run on the last day of every other month:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY; INTERVAL=2; BYMONTHDAY=-1;
```

Run hourly for the first three days of every month:

```
FREQ=HOURLY; BYMONTHDAY=1,2,3;
```

Run on the 60th, 120th and 180th days of the year:

```
FREQ=YEARLY; BYYEARDAY=60,120,180;
```

Run on the last workday of every month (assuming that workdays are Monday through Friday):

```
FREQ=MONTHLY; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI; BYSETPOS=-1
```

Here are some more complex examples which reference the following named schedules:

```
BEGIN
   sys.DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_schedule (
      schedule_name => 'COMPANY_HOLIDAYS',
      repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY; BYDATE=0704,0905,1124,1125,1225;');
   sys.DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_schedule (
      schedule_name => 'JUL4',
      repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY; BYMONTH=JUL; BYMONTHDAY=4;');
   sys.DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_schedule (
      schedule_name => 'MEM',
      repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY; BYMONTH=MAY; BYMONTHDAY=30;');
   sys.DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_schedule (
      schedule_name => 'LAB',
      repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY; BYMONTH=SEP; BYMONTHDAY=5;');
   sys.DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_schedule (
      schedule_name => 'LAST_SAT',
      repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY; BYDAY=SAT; BYSETPOS=-1;');
   sys.DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_schedule (
      schedule_name => 'END_QTR',
      repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY; BYDATE=0331,0630,0930,1231;');
   sys.DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_schedule (
    schedule_name => 'FISCAL_YEAR',
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=0301,0601,0901,1201;PERIODS=4;');
END;
/
```

Run on the last workday of every month, excluding company holidays:
FREQ=MONTHLY; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI; EXCLUDE=COMPANY_HOLIDAYS; BYSETPOS=-1

Run at noon every Friday and on company holidays:
FREQ=YEARLY; BYDAY=FRI;BYHOUR=12; INCLUDE=COMPANY_HOLIDAYS

Run on these three holidays: July 4th, Memorial Day, and Labor Day:
JUL4,MEM,LAB

Run on the last day of the month that is either a Saturday or last day of a quarter:

```
FREQ=MONTHLY; BYMONTHDAY=-1; INTERSECT=LAST_SAT,END_QTR
```

Run on the last Wednesday of every quarter of the fiscal year:

```
FREQ=FISCAL_YEAR;BYDAY=-1WED
```

Run on the last work day of the 2nd and 4th quarters of the fiscal year (assuming that workdays are Monday through Friday):

```
FREQ=FISCAL_YEAR;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI;BYPERIOD=2,4;BYSETPOS=-1
```