# scheduler job in oracle

Tags: oracle, scheduler, jobs

I want to create oracle dbms scheduler job, with these atributes:

```
FREQ=MINUTELY INTERVAL=10 BYDAY=MON TUE WED THU FRI 
BYHOUR=7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
```

But, beside that, I want in period from 14 to 16pm that this same job works on every 5 minutes, and before 14pm and after 16pm to work on 10minutes.

Comment: Please read this http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_linux_oracle_dbms_scheduler_create_job.htm . It will give you an insight of how to create a job.

Comment: should I create new job wich will work only from 14 to 16 pm in 5 minutes, so I would have 2 jobs  with same procedure

Comment: @AirBnb you may kindly refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617559/how-to-schedule-oracle-dbms-jobs-in-a-window/46618695#46618695

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to create schedules:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE (
  schedule_name     => 'my_first_schedule',
  start_date        => SYSTIMESTAMP,
  repeat_interval   => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=5;BYHOUR=14,15,16;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI',
  comments          => 'Every 10 minutes from 2pm to 4pm');
END;
/

BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE (
  schedule_name     => 'my_second_schedule',
  start_date        => SYSTIMESTAMP,
  repeat_interval   => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=10;BYHOUR=7,8,9,10,11,12,13,17,18;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI',
  comments          => 'Every 5 minutes from 7am to 2pm and from 5pm to 6pm');
END;
/

BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
     JOB_NAME           =>  'JOB',
     JOB_TYPE           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
     JOB_ACTION         =>  'SCHED_TEST_JOB_PROCEDURE',
     START_DATE         =>  SYSTIMESTAMP,
     REPEAT_INTERVAL    =>  'FREQ=my_first_schedule,my_second_schedule;',
     AUTO_DROP          =>  FALSE,
     ENABLED            =>  TRUE);
END;
/
```

Comment: Why should I use 3rd job?

Comment: there are 2 schedules and 1 job. the job uses the 2 schedules

Comment: Whether this third job is necessary..?

Comment: there is only 1 job, the first 2 are schedules. You need to create the schedules and then use them when you create your job

Comment: this is an absolutely great approach, i didnot know about that

Comment: Thanks! I asked you why shoukld i create 2 sch.jobs and one job? If I  create the 2 sch.jobs to start in specific time, why should  than I create thes simple job with   START_DATE         =>  SYSTIMESTAMP,
     REPEAT_INTERVAL    =>  'FREQ=my_first_schedule,my_second_schedule;',

Comment: You don’t understand. A schedule is just a repeating task, it doesn’t start anything. Creating  only the schedules is meaningless. The job will start a procedure or a plsql block at a frequency specified in the repeat interval.